# magento 1.9.2.2 any emails not sending

Tags: magento-1.9, email, cron

My magento server (live) not sending any emails
I try several methods to fixed this but anything doesn't work
**I correctly set Cron on my server its running every 5 minutes.**
here is what I do So far

Try Editing cron.php

After the line:

```
$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;
```

Add the following:

```
$isShellDisabled = true;
```

not working for me.

try instaling AOE scheduler it shows success but not sending any emails

[image]

try editing Template.php
Template.php is located in:

```
/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Email/Template.php
```

**Commenting below code**

```
if ($this->hasQueue() && $this->getQueue() instanceof Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue) {
    /** @var $emailQueue Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue */
        $emailQueue = $this->getQueue();
        $emailQueue->setMessageBody($text);
        $emailQueue->setMessageParameters(array(
                'subject'           => $subject,
                'return_path_email' => $returnPathEmail,
                'is_plain'          => $this->isPlain(),
                'from_email'        => $this->getSenderEmail(),
                'from_name'         => $this->getSenderName(),
                'reply_to'          => $this->getMail()->getReplyTo(),
                'return_to'         => $this->getMail()->getReturnPath(),
            ))
            ->addRecipients($emails, $names, Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_TO)
            ->addRecipients($this->_bccEmails, array(), Mage_Core_Model_Email_Queue::EMAIL_TYPE_BCC);
        $emailQueue->addMessageToQueue();
        return true;
    }
```

also try

```
app/code/core/Mage/Sales/Model/Order.php
```

changing lines

```
//$mailer->setQueue($emailQueue)->send(); Change To 

 $mailer->send();
```

**I also check sending simple mail using php mail its working**

EDIT
Also checked SMTP data
under ****System > Configuration->Advanced > System.**
also correct details**

I don't no what is the issue.
Also try truncating **core_email_queue** and **core_email_queue_recipients**
tables

Comment: check your server SMTP settings

Comment: yes I checked  smtp details are ok.

Comment: can you send mail with php `mail` function?

Comment: yes I can send mail with php mail function

Comment: Check your database cron_schedule. Ensure that the emails are getting queued and getting run. Also on the cron task make sure you have your email setup to receive any error reports.